# ListView make DecoratedBox overflow SizedBox area

Tags: flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) {
      var size = MediaQuery.of(_).size;

      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: size.width * 0.8,
            height: size.height * 0.2,
            child: DecoratedBox(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
          ),
        ]),
      );
    }));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MyApp(),
  );
}
```

i expect the red box to be 4/5 of the screen width wide. But it seems like the box spanned the entire screen width. ( Sorry for my bad English).

Is this a bug, or there are workaround to constrain the box size?
I am currently using Flutter 1.20.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run 2 full codes below 
You need to add constraints, you can wrap with `Center` or `Align` 
code snippet

```
Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: SizedBox(
```

please reference document https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

[image]

full code 1 with `Center`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) {
      var size = MediaQuery.of(_).size;

      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              height: size.height * 0.2,
              child: DecoratedBox(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      );
    }));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
```

full code 2 with `Align`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MaterialApp(home: Builder(builder: (_) {
      var size = MediaQuery.of(_).size;

      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              height: size.height * 0.2,
              child: DecoratedBox(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      );
    }));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ListView`, use `Column` or `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Actually, element of ListView is required to fill the ListView cross axis, so the decorated box is not overflowing the sized box ,but the sized box has to fill the cross axis of the ListView.